# Apache resource failed to start in Pacemaker

Tags: centos, apache-httpd, pacemaker, high-availability

I am using Pacemaker with Corosync to set up a basic Apache HA cluster with 3 nodes running CentOS7. For some reasons, I cannot get the apache resource started in pcs.

Cluster IP: 192.168.200.40

```
# pcs resource show ClusterIP
     Resource: ClusterIP (class=ocf provider=heartbeat type=IPaddr2)
      Attributes: cidr_netmask=24 ip=192.168.200.40
      Operations: monitor interval=20s (ClusterIP-monitor-interval-20s)
                  start interval=0s timeout=20s (ClusterIP-start-interval-0s)
                  stop interval=0s timeout=20s (ClusterIP-stop-interval-0s)



# pcs resource show WebServer
 Resource: WebServer (class=ocf provider=heartbeat type=apache)
  Attributes: configfile=/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf statusurl=http://localhost/server-status
  Operations: monitor interval=1min (WebServer-monitor-interval-1min)
              start interval=0s timeout=40s (WebServer-start-interval-0s)
              stop interval=0s timeout=60s (WebServer-stop-interval-0s)



# pcs status
Cluster name: 
WARNING: corosync and pacemaker node names do not match (IPs used in setup?)
Stack: corosync
Current DC: server3.example.com (version 1.1.18-11.el7_5.2-2b07d5c5a9) - partition with quorum
Last updated: Thu Jun  7 21:59:09 2018
Last change: Thu Jun  7 21:45:23 2018 by root via cibadmin on server1.example.com

3 nodes configured
2 resources configured

Online: [ server1.example.com server2.example.com server3.example.com ]

Full list of resources:

 ClusterIP  (ocf::heartbeat:IPaddr2):   Started server2.example.com
 WebServer  (ocf::heartbeat:apache):    Stopped

Failed Actions:
* WebServer_start_0 on server3.example.com 'unknown error' (1): call=49, status=Timed Out, exitreason='',
    last-rc-change='Thu Jun  7 21:46:03 2018', queued=0ms, exec=40002ms
* WebServer_start_0 on server1.example.com 'unknown error' (1): call=53, status=Timed Out, exitreason='',
    last-rc-change='Thu Jun  7 21:45:23 2018', queued=0ms, exec=40003ms
* WebServer_start_0 on server2.example.com 'unknown error' (1): call=47, status=Timed Out, exitreason='',
    last-rc-change='Thu Jun  7 21:46:43 2018', queued=1ms, exec=40002ms


Daemon Status:
  corosync: active/enabled
  pacemaker: active/enabled
  pcsd: active/enabled
```

The httpd instance is **enabled** and **running** on all three nodes.  The cluster IP and individual node IPs are able to access the web page. The ClusterIP resource also works well for failover. What may go wrong for the apache resource in this case?

Thank you very much!

Update:

Here is more information from the debug output. It seems the Apache is unable to bind to the port, but there is no error from the apache log, and `systemctl status httpd` gave all green on all nodes. I can open web pages via the cluster IP and each every node IP. The ClusterIP resource failover works fine, too. Any idea on why Apache resource doesn't work with pacemaker?

```
# pcs resource debug-start WebServer --full
Operation start for WebServer (ocf:heartbeat:apache) failed: 'Timed Out' (2)
 >  stderr: ERROR: (98)Address already in use: AH00072: make_sock: could not bind to address [::]:80 (98)Address already in use: AH00072: make_sock: could not bind to address 0.0.0.0:80 no listening sockets available, shutting down AH00015: Unable to open logs
 >  stderr: INFO: apache not running
 >  stderr: INFO: waiting for apache /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf to come up
 >  stderr: INFO: apache not running
 >  stderr: INFO: waiting for apache /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf to come up
 >  stderr: INFO: apache not running
 >  stderr: INFO: waiting for apache /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf to come up
 >  stderr: INFO: apache not running
```

Comment: It seems port 80 is already used! Kill the specific process using it (check with netstat) and retry again.

Comment: @marc Hi Marc, thanks for the clues. It turns out that I should NOT enable and start the httpd process with systemctl on every nodes, but rather let the pcs resource manager to take care of it. The problem was solved after I stopped and disabled the httpd process on all nodes.

Comment: Why would you want to run httpd on a VIP?

Answer (score 0):

I think it's because of `httpd` PID file location. I had the same issue and I resolved it by adding "`PidFile /var/run/httpd.pid`" in `httpd.conf` and disable the `webserver` resource and then starting `httpd` and `webserver` resource worked.

I know it's irrelevant to add answer after these long gap but it may help someone.